# how to protect my process being killed?

Tags: java, android

Some task killer app can kill my process like 360 safer. How do I protect my process from being killed? Or how do I detect if my app's process has been killed? I found tencent app can restart their app's process after being killed, but I don't know how they implement?

Comment: Why would wanna do that? As a user, i'll despise your application.

Comment: yeah, as a user i hate this. i just wonder how some app likes qq app can protect their app'process not being killed and can restart themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't protect from being killed nor can you be notified. The only way is to have a [sticky](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) Service running (which is NOT recommended, unless absolutely necessary). This service will be restarted automatically sometime later.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say how they do it, but [`ActivityManager#getRunningAppProcesses`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses%28%29) can be used to detect if your app has been killed. You can run a second service in the background to poll this status and restart your app if it is killed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.when app's process being killed,no more service will be alive. so run a second service can't help out.